# QGIS OpenLayers plugin doesn't work

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I tried to load base map from OpenLayers, but it doesn't work at all. QGIS popped up an error message showed below. What I noticed the slash foreword different way. I guess something wrong with the connect to Python.

How can I re-set it?

> An error has occurred while executing Python code:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File 
>   "C:/Users/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\weblayers\weblayer.py"
>
> ......
>
> Python version:
>
> 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]
>
> Python path:
>   ['C:/PROGRA~1/QGISPI~1/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing',
>
> ......

Comment: What version of QGIS are you running?

Comment: Also, what OS are you on?

Comment: What was the full traceback ?

Comment: Set the **Project** CRS to EPSG:3857 **before** loading any layer from the Openlayers plugin.

Comment: Windows 7,  QGIS 2.10.1 with Grass 6.4.3

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\weblayers\weblayer.py", line 97, in addLayer
    self._addLayerCallback(self)

  File "C:/Users/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 130, in addLayer
    layer = OpenlayersLayer(self.iface, self._olLayerTypeRegistry)

  File "C:/Users/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_layer.py", line 330, in __init__
    self.olWebPage = OLWebPage(self)

Comment: File "C:/Users/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_layer.py", line 48, in __init__
    proxy = getProxy()

  File "C:/Users/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\tools_network.py", line 42, in getProxy
    proxy.setPort(settings.value("/proxyPort", 10, type=int))

TypeError: unable to convert a QVariant of type 10 to a QMetaType of type 2

Comment: As a new user please take the [Tour] which starts to describe how this site works.  When providing requested clarifications please use the [edit] button beneath your question to revise it instead of creating a comment trail that potential answerers may or may not read.

Comment: Openlayers plugin is outdated. Use QuickMapServices (QMS) plugin instead. http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/quick_map_services/